# Get all data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

By now, I can get the data in the pivot table, but my question is, how can I get all the categories from my categories table and, if exists this category in my pivot table the input needs to be checked, how can I get this?

Project model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'header',
        'desc',
        'about',
        'url',
        'status'
    ];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withPivot('category_id');
    }
}
```

Category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'status'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class)->withPivot('project_id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function getEdit(Customer $customer, $project)
{
    return view('admin.pages.admin.clientes.projetos.edit', [
        'customer' => $customer,
        'project' => Project::where('id', $project)->firstOrFail(),
        'categories' => $this->categoryRepository->allCategories(), //return all categories in the categories table
        'title' => $customer->name
    ]);
}
```

Form

```
{!! Form::model($project, ['class' => 's-form', 'route' => ['project.update', $customer->id, $project->id]]) !!}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <div class="item-title required">Nome do projeto</div>
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Nome do projeto']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('name'))
            <div class="item-desc">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <div class="item-title">Descrição do projeto</div>
        {!! Form::text('desc', null, ['placeholder' => 'Descrição do projeto']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('desc'))
            <div class="item-desc">{{ $errors->first('desc') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <div class="item-title">Sobre o projeto</div>
        {!! Form::text('about', null, ['placeholder' => 'Sobre o projeto']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('about'))
            <div class="item-desc">{{ $errors->first('about') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <div class="item-title">URL do projeto</div>
        {!! Form::text('url', null, ['placeholder' => 'URL do projeto']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('url'))
            <div class="item-desc">{{ $errors->first('url') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item text">
        <div class="item-title">Imagem de cabeçalho do projeto</div>
        {!! Form::text('header', null, ['placeholder' => 'Imagem de cabeçalho do projeto']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('header'))
            <div class="item-desc">{{ $errors->first('header') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item checkbox inline">
        <div class="item-title">Categorias do projeto</div>
        @foreach($project->category as $category)
            {{-- Here I get all the categories, and the categories that exists in the pivot table will be checked--}}
            {{--<div class="s-checkbox s-radio-input">--}}
                {{--<input id="category-{{ str_slug($category->name) }}" type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{{ $category->id }}">--}}
                {{--<label for="category-{{ str_slug($category->name) }}"><span></span>{{ $category->name }}</label>--}}
            {{--</div>--}}
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item radio inline">
        <div class="item-title required">Status do projeto</div>
        <div class="s-radio-input">
            {!! Form::radio('status', '1', null, ['id' => 'categoria-ativo']) !!}
            <label for="categoria-ativo"><span></span>Ativa</label>
        </div>
        <div class="s-radio-input">
            {!! Form::radio('status', '0', null, ['id' => 'categoria-inativo']) !!}
            <label for="categoria-inativo"><span></span>Inativa</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s-form-item s-btn-group s-btns-right">
        <a href="{{ url('admin/clientes/editar') . '/' . $customer->id }}" class="s-btn cancel">Voltar</a>
        <input class="s-btn" type="submit" value="Atualizar">
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you need to select the project with its categories:

```
public function getEdit(Customer $customer, $project)
{
    return view('admin.pages.admin.clientes.projetos.edit', [
        'customer' => $customer,
        'project' => Project::with('category')->findOrFail($project),
        'categories' => $this->categoryRepository->allCategories(), //return all categories in the categories table
        'title' => $customer->name
    ]);
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div class="s-form-item checkbox inline">
    <div class="item-title">Categorias do projeto</div>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="s-checkbox s-radio-input">
            <input id="category-{{ str_slug($category->name) }}" type="checkbox" name="categories[]" {{$project->category->contains($category) ?  'checked="true"' : ''}} value="{{ $category->id }}">
            <label for="category-{{ str_slug($category->name) }}"><span></span>{{ $category->name }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

To update the Project with the selected categories:

```
$project = Project::findOrFail($project);
$project->category()->sync($request->input('categories', []));
$project->update($request->except(['_token','_method', 'categories']);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Worked like a charm! And how can I update it and all the pivots toggether? By now, withou updating my pivots this is my code: `Project::where('id', $project)->update($request->except(['_token','_method']));`

Comment: Please check out the updated answer. If this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).

Comment: At your service Sir!